# Adding rows and Running Multiple mySQL queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to figure out the best way of going about this.. I need to be able to append the table row with the input fields using JS so that multiple items can be entered with the same form but I need to somehow make each input have a unique name to target with PHP. From there I need to run a insert statement on each to insert into a mySQL db.. Im kind of stumped here

======================================================================

```
   <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
        <table class="addTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Customer Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Title" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Type" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $_POST['type']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="qty" placeholder="QTY" max="100" value="<?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: This is more of a conceptual thing question. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: have you considered working with array variables? Use ie. `qty[]` as the `name` attribute in your html. No need for unique names, and PHP treats it nicely as an array when you do `$_GET['qty']`.

Comment: "make each input have a unique name" : can you please explain what you mean by that? Do you mean a unique row ID?

Comment: Do you have access to a client-side UI library like jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array as name, for example:

```
   <form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
        <table class="addTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Customer Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Title" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Type" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $_POST['type']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="qty[]" placeholder="QTY" max="100" value="<?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?>">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Price" value="<?php echo $_POST['price']; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Then you can use something like:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']; $i++) {
  $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
  $type = $_POST['type'][$i];
  $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
  $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
  // make your query here
}
```

Also a small advice: in your html code don't directly echo $_POST values, first check if they exist, e. g. `<?= isset($_POST['price'])?$_POST['price']:""?>`

The `<?=` is a shortcut for `<?php echo`

The `isset($_POST['price'])?$_POST['price']:""` part is a shortcut for `if-else` statement. (It's called [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary))

It means the same as this:

```
if(isset($_POST['price'])) {
  echo $_POST['price'];
} else {
  echo "";
}
```

And the `isset()` itself checks whether the variable (or array key in this case) exists.

**EDIT: Updated info about appending**

If you can use jQuery, it's simple. If you don't use it, start using it :)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.some-class-of-your-button').click(function() {
    $('.addTable').append($('.addTable tr:nth-child(2)').clone());
    $('.addTable tr:last-child input').val("");
  });
});
</script>
```

Replace `some-class-of-your-button` with a class that your button has. The button must be outside of the table for this to work.

Comment: That helps alot.. Is there a simple way to make append another row of the inputs with JS?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Even better.. but how do I then set the name of each input with JQuery.. for example the first one should be name="name[1]" and then name="name[2]" and so on

Comment: You don't need to, when there is only [], it gets appended to the end of the array

Comment: THIS SOLVES ALL MY PROBLEMS!! Thank you very much